# How to set table row center Horizontal in table layout in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_24"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/cl_48"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/cl_48"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/vouchers_fdv_link_white" />


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/voucher_lines" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/cl_48"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/cl_48"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/vouchers_fdv_link_blue" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_15"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_top_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/text_ponts"
                    style="@style/Typeface.H1.Bold.TextDarkGrey"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="500pts"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_dark_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tfl_24"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text_ponts"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text_ponts"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text_ponts"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/fdv_points"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_mid_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tfl_16" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_voucher"
                    style="@style/Typeface.H1.Bold.TextDarkGrey"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/fdv_voucher_value"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_dark_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tfl_24"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/text_voucher"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text_voucher"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text_voucher"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/fdv_voucher"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_mid_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tfl_16" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

this is my xml layout code i kept in two table row in  first table row i kept linear layout inside that two imageview and view and in second row i kept Relative layout in which i kept 4 text view i have to  keep center horizontal  to first table row image view but when i set that property then it come left side please check  my code suggest me how to fix it .currntly its coming center and start from same position while i want to set center horizontal .https://www.draw.io/#LUntitled%20Diagram.xml please look this expected out put.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#008000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</TableRow>
```

Horizontally centers the content of the cell : TableLayout

```
 <TableRow>

<TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="your content"
            android:background="#FFFF0000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` property.

```
 <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >  
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_24"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
```

Comment: i set but its not working where i have to set  what happened when text increase then  it always start from start of image view while i want keep    text center from imageview\

Comment: i kept same thing but still its not working when text increase it always move right side not it not setting center to imageview

Comment: what actually do you want TableRow center-horizontal or textview ??

Comment: see there are  two image view in table row first and table row second there are two text view in top and bottom two textview i want textview  center with image view when text increase  then also it should center currently it always start from left  second textview start with end both text view touch when text increase i want keep it inc enter please look my  digram you will understand what problem i am facing

Comment: Remove this:-    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

Comment: after removing still same issue  it always start from top image view when text increase

Answer (score 0):

> android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

this used to set the layout content in the center of layout horizontally

Whereas if you want it completely in center you might  have to use

> android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: center_inParent there is no such property is there @Akash Pal

Comment: oops sorry i meant android:layout_gravity="center"

Comment: well thats  because you used  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

Comment: instead you couls use android:id to set it according to your need inside of the relative Layout

Comment: how  can you please suggest me

Comment: Also i found that you are using layout:gravity="center" in the table Layout you should not be using that if you want the content to be shown from start

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in code like this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Or you can use the interface in the IDE.

[horizontal_center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNvCc.png)